# Rspec results are different when running one and all specs

Tags: ruby, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

Here's the source code https://github.com/tenzan/eshop

When I run a specific spec by
`rspec spec/features/application_controller_spec.rb`, test passes.

But when I run all by executing `rspec`, it's giving me error for the spec above:

```
Failures:

  1) Admin::ApplicationController GET #index returns http success
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
       expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 302
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/application_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.61968 seconds (files took 1.53 seconds to load)
12 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/admin/application_controller_spec.rb:6 # Admin::ApplicationController GET #index returns http success
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: most likely something is leaking between tests.

Comment: Who do you clear the database after running a test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you run alone is not the one that fails when you run the whole suite ;-)

`rspec spec/features/application_controller_spec.rb` --> is perfectly alright.

`rspec spec/controllers/admin/application_controller_spec.rb:6` --> Fails in any case, since there is no authenticated user.

And a few tips: you can use `--require rails_helper` instead of `--require spec_helper` in the .rspec file, then you won't need to require it in every test file. And a shortcut: it is possible to use simple `describe` instead of `RSpec.describe`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems instead of dealing with `spec/controllers/admin/application_controller_spec.rb`, I mistakenly created `spec/features/application_controller_spec.rb`. LOL. Thanks a lot for the other 2 tips.